# These sets are written in set generator form. Write the sets in list of elements form.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

These sets are written in *set generator form*. Write the sets in *list of elements form*.

a)$\{\frac{1}{n}: n = 1,2,3,4\}$

b)$\{n^2-n: n = 0,1,2,3,4\}$

I have no idea how to even attempt this...If someone can show me just one or an example of one being done I know for a fact I can do the rest. My book is awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a)**

Your set, rewritten:

$\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \{1,2,3,4\}\}$

The set given by elements:

$\{\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}\}$

They all fulfill the requirment that the denominator is either 1,2,3 or 4 while the numerator is 1.

**b)**

$\{n^2 - n : n \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}\}$

It is clear that

$0^2 - 0 = 0$

$1^2 - 1 = 0$

$2^2 - 2 = 2$

$3^2 - 3 = 6$

$4^2 - 4 = 12$

i.e the set is:

$\{0,2,6,12\}$

Comment: Did you mean to say that the set given by elements: {1/1,1/2,1/3,1/4}?

Comment: you wrote: {1/2, 1/2...} so 1/2 is not equal to 1 unless I'm missing something.. Just trying to figure out why you wrote 1/2 twice...

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer.

Comment: So would the second set be {0,2,6,12} for b?

Comment: Correct - also added to answer